# Cant access router config page after connecting internet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I have a WD N900 WiFi router (dual band). I got it second hand.

When I just connect everything, I cannot access 192.168.1.1.

When I disconnect everything, hold reset for 10 seconds, only connect pc cable, I can access settings. I set everything.

As soon as I plug in the cable to the adsl modem, I can't access 192.168.1.1 anymore. "not found".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ADSL modem is likely running NAT and a DHCP server on the same network as your router (192.168.1.0/24), so that when you request 192.168.1.1 its getting confused on how to correctly route the packet.  You have a couple options:

1. Bridge your ADSL modem connection to the router (prefered).  In this secnario the modem will only act as a modem, not as a router.
2. Change the IP range for either the modem or your router so they're not conflicting.  This will likely leave you in a situation where you are behind 2 levels of NAT, one on the modem and one on your router, which is not advisable.
3. Disable the DHCP server on your router and plug the modem into one of the LAN ports on your router rather than the WAN port.  In this situation the router would be used more as an Wi-Fi Access Point rather than a router.

Comment: You are right that was the problem. I set my modem as a bridge. At first I couldn't access the modem's config as well, but added :8080. The x.x.1.1 still doesn't give acces to the router though. I guess I need a port number as well. Any idea on how to find it? Zyxel model did not list ports.

Comment: Typically your router should be on the default port, 80.  You might also try a https connection.  You still might have an IP conflict too.   I'm assuming your modem still has a static IP address assigned to it.  I would probably change the modem to be 192.168.1.2 and leave the router at 192.168.1.1

Comment: Oh my, when looking for mybooklive network hard disk, I accidentally found the router setup page at 192.168.6.1. No idea if it's because of the bridge setting or not. But it works : )

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your ADSL modem might be giving you an internal address of the same range. Change the IP range to 172. or 10. and you should still be able to access it.